# Do migrated questions count towards the question ban?

Tags: support, migration, post-ban

I saw [this user's profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3105908/genghis). 3 out of 4 old questions were migrated from Stack Overflow to other sites and the 4th one does not fit Stack Overflow either and was already closed.

Do migrated questions count towards the question ban or could a user just go on and ask off-topic question that get migrated?

Comment: Two out of four.  Even without those questions, the account would probably still be question-banned.  Your ability to ask on the correct site is just as important as your ability to ask a good question.

Comment: But when I click 3 questions I get redirected to other sites. Why is it only 2 out of 4?

Comment: [His comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20924357/why-my-virtual-machine-do-not-loading-anymore#comment31417721_20924357) on his most recent question just smacks of complete ignorance.  It is probably good his question did not get migrated as he seems like he won't learn to ask on the appropriate site unless he does it himself.

Comment: Migration stubs are deleted once they are already more than 30 days old, and the fact that a question is deleted doesn't count towards a ban if it's more than 30 days old once it's deleted.

Comment: @Sonic I think it's 60...?

Comment: @ɪBᴜɢ No, it's 30, according to the ban FAQ.

Comment: I must have mixed it up with the Curious badge family.