# Do duplicate and migrated question count as closed for some criteria?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, migrated-questions

I've read the FAQ but still not sure.

Criteria for certain mechanics, like a question ban, involve "badly received" posts, one of which is "closed questions". Also "Curious" badge requires "a positive question record", which takes this into account.

As the FAQ says, reasons like off-topic, too broad, unclear what you're asking are given for closing a question. So does the closing banner, which says "**put on hold/closed** by [user] for [reason]". But duplicate questions are given "**marked as** duplicate by ...".

Comment: @JasonC I don't agree with your statement of duplicity. I meant a "general criteria" (see edit).

Comment: I guess. I took back the vote. But doesn't it seem too broad now? The general answer to your question is: "Yes". Do you need anything beyond that?

Comment: Related: [Will asking too many duplicate questions lead to a question ban?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/188291/230261) and [Do migrated questions count towards the question ban?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214929/230261).

Comment: @JasonC It's not too broad. The criteria are only used for a few things, like (AFAIK) the ban and one badge. And I'm not asking about *all* kinds of closing, just dup & mig. It's acceptable to answer the two in one place, I think.