# Do non-duplicate closed questions contribute to a post ban?

Tags: support, closed-questions, post-ban

We know from the [FAQ on duplicate questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10844/165261) that:

> [T]here's no automatic penalty if your question gets marked as a duplicate of another.

via an edit from Tim Post with the summary:

> Other misconception: dupes don't automatically get you banned or something, it's the votes that patterns of low quality tend to attract that does that.

Does the same logic (only the score matters, not the closure itself) apply to other close reasons, or are duplicate closures special-cased?

Comment: A note in case it's not clear: this is about the general workings of the system, not any specific example.  In particular, I'm not (and never have been) post-banned on any site.

Comment: If I am not mistaken the only closure that wouldn’t be automatically deleted eventually would be a duplicate closure.  I would imagine a migration would also not count towards a question ban.  The closure and eventual deletion itself likely isn’t considered but a deleted question cannot be voted on, which means no upvotes or reversals of downvotes, which means they could count (but the votes themselves is the true cause). Hopefully, this can be answered, without revealing to much about the mechanics of a question ban.

Comment: FTR: I use this query: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/885476/am-i-quality-banned-for-questions which seems to be wrong, or so I'm told by both Animuson and Martijn. But when I use it on accounts that complain on Meta the outcome of the query has never let me down.

Comment: So according to this questions closed as duplicate should be excluded from the count in the formula in the query of @rene?

Comment: @Luuklag yeah, that looks like to be the case

Comment: @Ramhound I think you're mistaken. A closed question with positive score or at least 1 answer normally won't get Roomba'd. The exception is that a closed question with no answers and a score of 1 gets deleted if the OP's account has been deleted. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/334566 & https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/334566

Comment: Related, possible dupe: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252046/when-does-the-question-ban-get-applied See also Jeff Atwood's answer on this question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86982/should-i-avoid-deleting-my-questions/

Comment: Another possible duplicate: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188291/will-asking-too-many-duplicate-questions-lead-to-a-question-ban

Comment: Same question but no answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296689/do-duplicate-and-migrated-question-count-as-closed-for-some-criteria